# How do I use an SCSS variable from a package imported/required by Webpack?

Tags: sass, npm, webpack

I'm rewriting a bunch of HTML+CSS+JS to be more modular. I'm starting simply and have two NPM packages:

1. **Core** has some SCSS:

   index.js

   ```
   require("./styles/variables.scss");
   require("./styles/test-import.scss");
   ```

   styles/variables.scss

   ```
   $color-primary: rgb(0, 123, 196);
   $color-type-main: rgb(51, 51, 51);
   ```

   styles/test-import.scss

   ```
   @import "variables";
   body { background: $color-primary }
   ```
2. **Test** requires **Core** and wants to use a variable:

   index.js

   ```
   require("core");
   require("./styles/test.scss");
   ```

   styles/test.scss

   ```
   body { background: $color-primary; }
   ```

Core builds great using Webpack. Test fails because it can't find $color-primary.

One option I've considered is importing the variables file directly, i.e.

```
require("./node_modules/core/styles/variables");
```

...but that doesn't seem very scalable. NPM could at any time decide to change how they structure their directories.

Answer (score 1):

You do have to explicitly load any dependencies (e.g. your variables partial) in every Sass file, because each one is compiled in isolation. However, to make it easier:

- you can use [baggage-loader](https://github.com/deepsweet/baggage-loader/) to automatically add a `require` to files. Using the loader config's regex can help you narrow down where the insertion happens if you don't need it everywhere.
- If you prefix your imports with `, webpack will use its `require` resolution to resolve the import. Since webpack lets you specify aliases for resolution (and a bunch of other flexible options), you can abstract out the actual location of stuff you need to import, and if the required file needs to move, just update your webpack resolver config.